# Multiplying signals in discrete-time vs continuous-time

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, continuous-signals, reconstruction, theory

Given two discrete-time signals $a[n]$, $b[n]$ and its product $c[n]=a[n] b[n]$. The ideally interpolated, continuous-time version of $c[n]$ is

\begin{align}
c_1(t)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a[n] b[n] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n T}{T}\right) .
\end{align}

Now I would like to perform this multiplication in continuous-time using the interpolated versions of $a[n]$ and $b[n]$:

\begin{align}
c_2(t) &= \left(\sum_{n_1=-\infty}^{\infty} a[n_1] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n_1 T}{T}\right)\right) \left(\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^{\infty} b[n_2] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n_2 T}{T}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{n_1=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^{\infty} a[n_1] b[n_2] \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n_1 T}{T}\right)   \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t-n_2 T}{T}\right) .
\end{align}

Suddenly I end up with a double-sum and the cross terms $n_1\neq n_2$ are nonzero.

Why?
What do I need to do to arrive in a form similar as $c_1(t)$ with just one sum?

Comment: Ask yourself when are the $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ functions zero?  And when are they non-zero?

Comment: They are only zero for $t=n_i T, n_i \neq 0$. I understand your comment if I’d be only interested in the values at this point. However, I have a continuous signal.

Comment: so, since it is the outer summation, fix $n_1$ to an integer value.  what values of $n_2$ will result in the product in that double summation being zero?  what values of $n_2$ would it not be zero?

Comment: oh, and evaluate $c_2(t)$ at the sampling instances, $t=nT$.

$$c_2(nT) = \sum_{n_1=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^{\infty} a[n_1] b[n_2] \operatorname{sinc}(n-n_1) \operatorname{sinc}(n-n_2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reached a puzzling conclusion about $c_1(t) = c_2(t)$, and wonder whether you made a mistake in deriving them, or if the equality is indeed correct then how to explain it, perhaps by explicitly deriving one from the other.

I cannot tell whether it's possible to explicitly manipulate the double summation in $c_2(t)$ so as to convert it into the single summation of $c_1(t)$. It may be possible, I haven't tried. But sometimes it's not possible to explicitly show it, and instead, we have to rely on *indirect* evidence to confirm the equality and use the equality for our advantage if possible.

One such example is the Fourier transform of the constant $1$ :

$$ \mathcal{F}\{1\} = 2\pi \delta(\omega) \tag{0} $$

The equality in Eq.0 is not derived by explicitly evaluating the forward Fourier integral, but instead, deduced from  the **duality** property of CTFT, and given that Fourier transform of $\delta(t)$ is $1$.

At the end of the analysis, we conclude that the validity of the equality $c_1(t) = c_2(t)$ is a consequence of the Nyquist sampling theorem;i.e., the **truth** of the equality is imposed by the sampling theorem, rather than a result of explicit algebraic manipulations of $c_2(t)$ into $c_1(t)$ or vice versa. And indeed, this is a useful side application of the theorem to prove that some equation is true which is very hard, if not impossible, to do so otherwise.

Let me show you, therefore, an indirect way of imposing the equality.

Let all signals $a(t),b(t)$, and $c(t)=a(t)b(t)$ are **sufficiently** bandlimited so that we can avoid aliasing.

Observe impulse train modulation relation:

$$ x_s(t) = x(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) ~ \cdot \cdot \cdot ~ \delta_T(t) = x(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \tag{1}$$

where  $ ~\delta_T(t) = \sum_n \delta(t-nT)$.

Also observe the interpolation relation :
$$ \left( x(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \right) \star h(t) = x(t) \tag {2}$$

where $~h(t) = \text{sinc}(t/T) ~$ is the ideal lowpass brickwall interpolation filter.

We will use Eqs. 1 & 2 to derive alternative but equivalent expressions for the samples $c_s(t)$ of $c(t)$ and achieve the single and double sum versions $c_1(t)$ and $c_2(t)$.

**The Double Sum :**
$$
\begin{align}
c(t) &= c_s(t) \star h(t) \\
&= \left( c(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \right) \star h(t) \\
&= \left( a(t) \cdot b(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \right) \star h(t) &\text{Multiply then sample}\\
&= a(t)b(t)  &\text{by Eq.2} \\
&= \left( \sum_n a[n] h(t-nT) \right) \left( \sum_m b[m] h(t-mT) \right) \\
&= \sum_n \sum_m a[n] b[n] ~ h(t-nT) ~ h(t-mT) \\
\end{align}
$$

**The Single Sum :**

$$
\begin{align}
c(t) &= c_s(t) \star h(t) \\
&= \left( a(t) \cdot b(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \right) \star h(t) \\
&= \left( a(t) \cdot \delta_T(t) \cdot b(t) \cdot \delta(t) \right) \star h(t) &\text{by Eq.1} \\
&= \left( a_s(t) \cdot b_s(t) \right) \star h(t) &\text{Sample then multiply} \\
&= \left( \sum_n a[n] \delta(t-nT) \right) \left( \sum_m b[m] \delta(t-mT) \right) \star h(t) \\
&= \left( \sum_n \sum_m a[n]b[m] \delta((m-n)T) \cdot \delta(t-mT) \right) \star h(t) \\
&= \sum_n a[n] \left( \sum_m b[m] \left[ \delta((m-n)T)\delta(t-mT) \star h(t) \right] \right) \\
&= \sum_n a[n] \left( \sum_m b[m] \delta((m-n)T)) h(t-mT) \right) \\
&= \sum_n a[n]b[n] h(t-nT)
\end{align}
$$

The sampling relations are  :

$$a_s(t) = a(t) \delta_T(t) = \sum_n a[n] \delta(t-nT) \tag{3}$$
$$b_s(t) = b(t) \delta_T(t) = \sum_m b[m] \delta(t-mT) \tag{4}$$
$$c_s(t) = c(t) \delta_T(t) = \sum_n c[n] \delta(t-nT) \tag{5}$$

We can get back $a(t),b(t)$,and $c(t)$ by ideal bandlimited interpolation of their samples $a[n],b[n]$,and $c[n]$ :

$$a(t) = a_s(t) \star h(t)= \sum_n a[n] \text{sinc}((t-nT)/T) \tag{6}$$
$$b(t) = b_s(t) \star h(t)= \sum_m b[m] \text{sinc}((t-mT)/T) \tag{7}$$
$$c(t) = c_s(t) \star h(t)= \sum_n c[n] \text{sinc}((t-nT)/T) \tag{8}$$

Comment: because, Over, the OP is reconstructing $c_1(t)$ out of the multiplied product of only the samples.

Comment: remember Fat32 that the frequency response $H(f)$ associated with your impulse response $h(t)$ does not have a passband gain of 1 (or 0 dB).  you may run into a problem with dimension.  usually impulse responses have dimension of 1/time.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes $h(t)$ is an ideal lowpass brickwall filter with cutoff frequency $\omega_c = \pi/T$ and gain of $T$...

Comment: what's a gain of $T$ mean?  how many dB is it?

Comment: and in the convolution integral, $$ y(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(u) x(t-u) \ \mathrm{d}u $$, if $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the same species of animal, what is the dimension of $h(t)$ if $t$ has dimension of time?

Comment: Before [our friend started fucking it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem&diff=58603453&oldid=57554446) you might want to check out this pedagogical problem with the presentation of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem that most (but not all) textbooks have.  Actual reconstruction filters do not have passband gain of dimension time.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson ok !! ;-)  but this is way out of context right now... May be we shall discuss the whole topic of *unita* in a more proper question of its own. But I think this is not that question. For now, unit of $h(t)$ is whatever consistent with the application.

Comment: but your answer in this case is gonna get messed up.

Comment: is the area "unitless"?  is the area under the curve in an integral "unitless"?  is the Riemann sum of an integral of, say, speed w.r.t. time, is that Riemann sum unitless? 
 are the little $\Delta t$ factors unitless?  is $v(t)$ unitless?  and, while Ced and BobK got their unit spiel all fucked up, your position above is just about as bad.

Comment: and you will get wrong answers with the Sampling Theorem if you don't cross your i's and dot your t's.

Comment: but that is not the $v(t)$ going into the integral.  nor is the width of the Riemann rectangles $\Delta t$.  when you do integrals of functions that have physically meaningful dimension, you **do** have to be careful with dimension and if it's not dimensionless, you have to be careful with the units.

Comment: and you will get the wrong answer here if you are not careful with the dimension of quantity.  inside the computer or DSP, those samples are dimensionless numbers, but once they are output and a signal reconstructed, it's a physical signal operating in physical time.  the $\mathrm{d}t$ in the convolution integral has dimension of time.  you **do** have to worry about that, if you don't want to fuck things up.

Comment: [In the EE forum, I posted an answer (to my own question) that has a quick rundown of the Sampling Theorem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206482/exactly-what-is-the-role-of-the-zero-order-hold-in-a-hybrid-analog-digital-sampl/207926#207926) (without using the [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)) and then applying that to the notion of the Zero-order Hold (ZOH).

Comment: There is a reason why so many textbooks get the ZOH wrong which literally leads to errors, especially in applications of digital control when the ZOH is in a feedback loop.  in a feedback loop, you better the hell get your scaling exactly right.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson My point is that *this question* does not require a specific discussion on units... I believe we can do it on a more appropriate question. Deleting my comments on *units*.

Comment: And your point misses the point i was making that putting the $T$ in the wrong place can lead to error in reconstruction.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson ok, I get it now. Do you mean this ideal interpolation filter $$h(t) = \text{sinc}(t/T) = \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{T}t)}{\frac{\pi}{T}t}$$ is wrong ?

Comment: yup.  but $$ h(t) = \tfrac{1}{T} \operatorname{sinc}(\tfrac{t}{T}) $$ is correct.  And a sampling function $$ x_\mathrm{s}(t) = x(t) \cdot T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-nT) $$ is correct.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The ideal D/C converting interpolation filter $H(\omega)$ is defined to have a gain of $T$ at the passband $|\omega| < \pi/T$. This gain of $T$ will cancel the pre-scaling $1/T$ imposed on the periodic spectrum of $x_s(t)$ due to impulse train sampling. That's the convention I'm using, and it seems right to me. Why change it..? It's not a *practical* interpolator such as ZOH, may be the scale dissapears due to *finite duration* of reconstruction pulses, but for the *ideal* case of zero duration impulse based reconstruction, it remains.

Comment: nope.  your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson sorry, I don't agree... ;-) Your sampling function is unnecessarily scaled by $T$, therefore you omit the interpolation filter gain... good for you, bad for me ;-)

Comment: You don't have to agree.  But if you want to understand reconstruction correctly, you need to lose the $T$ in the passband gain of the brickwall LPF.  The definition of the reconstruction filter is that it removes all of the images except the original image which is passed **unchanged**.  With the reconstructed spectrum unchanged from the original, so also is the reconstructed signal in the time domain unchanged from the original.

Comment: And until you can tell me how many dB a linear gain of $T$ is, you're stuck in the mud.  Same about the gain, at DC, of the Zero-order hold effect.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Alright then, instead of posting (and wasting) it here why don't you post your claims to Oppenheim, Proakis, Haykin, Papoulis, Lathi, Kailath etc. so that they can also "correct" their books before a disaster happens. :-)) I think they should give you a satisfactory answer that I'm missing...

Comment: Fat, I've been here (harping about this pedagogical issue) literally for decades.  I'm sure one can find a record of it on *comp.dsp* that exists from the turn of the century. [I just now uploaded the first paper I wrote saying this in 1988](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344448208_Effect_of_DACDeglitching_on_FrequencyResponse).  The paper is totally obsolete now (Sigma-Delta made it obsolete). Sometime in 2010 I visited Alan Oppenhiem at MIT and asked him about this.  He didn't think it was important.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Wow that's a very nice paper! But it's about **practical** DAC circuitry? We are dealing with **ideal** sampling and interpolation? ZOH , SOH kind of circuits have their very own implications on the reconstruction filter and that's pretty well-known. If you employ a nonideal (say flat-top) sampling, then the reconstruction filter will be different. I have no objection. This whole discussion is well deviated from the main concern of the problem...

Comment: oh, dear, Fat. it's **all** ideal.  it's just math.  it's no different (but these deglitchers are more complicated, although very obsolete now) than determining the effect of the ZOH (or any other reconstruction scheme).  you start with: $$ x_\mathrm{s}(t) = T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \delta(t-nT) $$ and then you ask the question: *"What LTI system turns that function $x_\mathrm{s}(t)$ into the output I am looking for?"* That's it.  And if you leave off the $T$ you'll get the wrong answer. That's what happened to Barry Blesser as referenced in my 1988 paper.